# How do I see where in the Class Hierarchy a Method was defined and Overridden in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, abstract-syntax-tree

Is there a way to know whether or not a method has been overridden by a subclass programmatically?  Something that works like this:

```
class BaseModel
  def create
    puts "superclass"
  end
end

class SomeModel < BaseModel
  def create
    puts "subclass"
  end
end

puts SomeModel.overridden_instance_methods #=> [:create]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SomeModel.instance_methods(false) & BaseModel.instance_methods
```

The `false` makes `instance_methods` not include inherited methods. We then use set intersection to find all the methods that were defined on SomeModel which have previously been defined on BaseModel (or Object).

Comment: BTW: if you don't know the direct superclass of `SomeModel` beforehand, you can use `SomeModel.superclass` instead of `BaseModel`. That way, you can package this functionality up in a reusable method. Something like `class Class; def overriden_methods; instance_methods(false) & superclass.instance_methods end end` And then: `SomeModel.overriden_methods`

Comment: Be aware, though, that this won't catch cases where SomeModel mixed-in a module that defined create(). This expression will only give you the methods that SomeModel has directly overridden.

Comment: [Follow up question for modules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488429/how-do-you-list-included-modules-in-a-ruby-class)