# determine the context on which a method runs

Tags: ruby

```
class Class
  def mixin_ancestors(include_ancestors=true)
    ancestors.take_while {|a| include_ancestors || a != superclass }.
    select {|ancestor| ancestor.instance_of?(Module) }
  end
end

class MyTestClass

end
```

Took the above code from [How do you list included Modules in a Ruby Class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488429/how-do-you-list-included-modules-in-a-ruby-class)

I have following questions.

1)  By saying 'def mixin_ancestors' as in the above code  we are defining an instance method. But doing 'a = MyTestClass.new ; a.mixin_ancestors' says undefined method mixin_ancestors.

2)  So I did ‘MyTestClass. mixin_ancestors’. It gave me a list .

3)  I think ‘ancestors’ is a method. In which context does the ‘ancestors’ method runs. To find that I did ‘method(ancestors).owner’ but got error-  `method: [MyTestClass, Object, Kernel, BasicObject] is not a symbol (TypeError).`  Got this trick from my own previous question [Determine the class to which a method belongs in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7245946/determine-the-class-to-which-a-method-belongs-in-rails)

4)  Like third point on which context does `superclass` method in the above code runs.

Thanks for the helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 & 2) We are defining an instance method of `Class` which means it will be a class method for other objects.

3) It is run within `Class` object, so it is a method of `Class` or one of it's ancestors (it's actually in `BasicObject`)

4) It is run in context of `Class` object (or of object extending it)

Comment: My understanding from your answer is. 

The context (that is self) inside `mixin_ancestors` points to `MyTestClass` which is an instance of `Class`.
By calling methods like `ancestors`,`superclass` inside `mixin_ancestors` we are actually invoking these methods on `MyTestClass` itself.

`MyTestClass` got the `superclass` method at its class level from `Class`, where it should be defined at instance level.
`MyTestClass` got the `ancestors` method at its class level from `Module`, where it should be defined at instance level.

Comment: That seems to be correct. The key is to remember that classes are objects in Ruby too.

Answer (score 0):

In ruby, Class is a class for class object. In your example, MyTestClass is an instance of class Class. So, mixin_ancestor is an instance method for these objects.

In 3), you should use method(:ancestors), but you simply call it - and it returned an array - as you can see in output - [MyTestClass, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]

4) self here is an instance of Class

I strongly recommend you to buy [http://www.amazon.com/Metaprogramming-Ruby-Program-Like-Pros/dp/1934356476](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356476) - this book explains ruby in excellent way!

Comment: mixin_ancestor is a class level method for all our custom defined classes. But you have said its instance method. is it correct ?

Comment: Yes, it is instance methods (in ruby object model), because class is an instance of Class class